# Convert a list of str into a single huge string

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I have a list of str and I want to convert it into a single string

```
      poem = ['The time is here, the Captain said\n',
     'To talk about various things: boots - and planes - and wax,\n',
     'Of carrots; and queens.\n'
     'And why the sea is blue;\n'
     'and whether pigs can fly.\n']
```

I need to convert this list into one big string

I tried this approach:

```
for words in poem:
    stripped = word.strip('\n')
```

Am I doing it correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can first use [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and then replace `"\n"` with a space:

```
whole_string = ''.join(poem).replace('\n, ' ')
print whole_string
```

**Output:**

```
The time is here, the Captain said To talk about various things: boots - and planes - and wax, Of carrots; and queens. And why the sea is blue; and whether pigs can fly.
```